# computing the correction to free propagator in $\phi^4$ theory

Tags: quantum-field-theory

I want to calculate the first order correction to the free propagator in $\phi^4$ theory. Srednicki "calculates" it in chapter 31, where he directly writes the answer and tells us to use the "usual bag of tricks" in section 14 to get the answer. The problem is, I'm unsure which tricks he's referring to. We have eq. (31.3):
\begin{equation}
\Delta (0) = \int \frac{d^d l}{2 \pi ^d} \frac{1}{l^2 + m^2 + i\epsilon}
\end{equation}
And after solving and making a Wick rotation from $l_0$ to $iq_0$, we have almost the same equation.
\begin{equation}
\Delta (0) = i \int \frac{d^d q}{2 \pi ^d} \frac{1}{q^2 + m^2}
\end{equation}
With the $\epsilon$ term now irrelevant since we've made the rotation. Now here's where it gets dicey. In the original analysis Srednicki differentiated the expression twice with respect to incoming/outgoing momentum k to get an expression that could be solved in d<8 dimensions (eq. 14.19). However, in the $\phi^4$ theory, I see no such way out: the k dependence simply doesn't exist. And in d = 4 dimensions we have the numerator growing much faster than the denominator and hence the integral is infinite at infinite momentum cutoff. How do I get around this?

Comment: Link: https://web.physics.ucsb.edu/~mark/qft.html

Comment: Hint: Srednicki is instead using [dimensional regularization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dimensional_regularization).